# What is difference between application.rb and environment.rb in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Rails and I have good knowledge of ASP.net. In ASP.net web applications I have one `web.config` to do all my settings, but in Rails there are several config files and I would like to know now, what are the differences between them and what is the purpose of these files are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically the different config files build together the `web.config` as you know it from ASP.net.

`environment.rb`

Rails has different run-levels, like ASP.net has it's environments too. In the `environment.rb` file you configure these run-levels. For example, you could use it to have some special settings for your development stage, which are usefull for debugging.

`application.rb`

The purpose of this file is to configure things for the whole application like encoding.

You can find some more information in the [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html#config-environment-rb), like it was mentioned by davids.

Answer (score 2):

From the [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html#config-environment-rb):

> **config/environment.rb**
>
> This file is the common file required by config.ru (rails server) and Passenger. This is where these two ways
>   to run the server meet; everything before this point has been Rack and
>   Rails setup.
>
> This file begins with requiring config/application.rb.
>
> **config/application.rb**
>
> This file requires config/boot.rb, but only if it hasn’t been required before, which would be the case in rails
>   server but wouldn’t be the case with Passenger.
>
> Then the fun begins!